# Two tables as parameters of user defined function

Tags: sql-server, function, compare, udf

I am trying to create a function in SQL SERVER which I can use to compare two tables, to check if they are identical. I do that with two excepts.

The Tables are supposed to be exactly the same, with the same data formats and column names as well as all values identical in both tables. This will be a manual check, so if differences are there, a thrown error is not a problem. The aim is just to see if two approaches of creating the tables leads to the same tables.

I am really new to functions in SQL, so I am not sure how to solve the problem. 
I want to pass both tables as parameters to the function, to get something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DIFFERING_ROWS
(@TABLE1, @TABLE2)
RETURNS TABLE

AS
RETURN (
    SELECT *, 'A_not_B' as [Difference] FROM @TABLE1
    except
    SELECT *, 'A_not_B' as [Difference] FROM @TABLE2
    union all
    SELECT *, 'B_not_A' as [Difference] FROM @TABLE2
    except
    SELECT *, 'B_not_A' as [Difference] FROM @TABLE1
    )
END
```

How is this implemented correctly?
Can anybody help me?

Comment: This is going to be highly prone to error. If the two tables don't have the exact same columns and datatypes it is going to fail. That of course all depends first on getting this out of a function and into dynamic sql.

Comment: Unless of course you are trying to use table valued parameters which then you could do this in a function. But the code you posted doesn't have a datatype so we are kind of guessing here.

Comment: Oh yeah, I will make that clear in the question. The Tables are supposed to be exactly the same, with the same data formats and column names. This will be a manual check, so if differences are there, a thrown error is not a problem.

Comment: But are you passing the name of the tables or table valued parameters? What is the datatype of the two tables?

Comment: I want to pass the name of the two tables, so that i can run these select statements on them. I have multiple pairs of two tables each. For each pair, I need to know if I produced an exact copy of the table, with identical values.

Comment: OK. So then change to a procedure and convert the queries to dynamic sql. Be sure you wrap your table names with QUOTENAME. It will help when you have spaces and such in the name and also will greatly help minimize the risk of sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a function.   The only way you can pass table names as parameters is to use Dynamic SQL, and Dynamic SQL is not allowed in functions.   You CAN do it with a stored procedure.

Comment: Then how would this look like as a stored procedure?

Comment: Instead of using RETURN, the stored procedure would simply do the SELECT, using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this stored procedure that counts if the tables have the same column_names:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkEqualTables
@table1 varchar(100),
@table2 varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @xCount int;

(SELECT @xCount = COUNT(*) from (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name=@table1) base
         where column_name not in (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name=@table2))

IF(@xCount <= 0)    
    print 'Tables are equal!';
ELSE
    print 'Tables are not equal!'    

END
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the OP is interested in the content, not the actual columns.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I took the information from the answers and comments and researched about how to put this into procedures, and this is what I built:

I think this does what I want:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkEqualTables
@table1 nvarchar(100),
@table2 nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);

SET @SQL =  'SELECT * FROM '    + @TABLE1 +
            'except
            SELECT * FROM '     + @TABLE2 +
            'union all
            SELECT * FROM '     + @TABLE2 +
            'except
            SELECT * FROM '     + @TABLE1    
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

END
```